# How to achieve smaller font size for email on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, html-email

I have to modify an existing email template.  When the email is viewed on a smartphone, the 16px font size is too big and causes unwanted line breaks.

How can I cause the font size to be smaller only on mobile devices?

AFIK I cannot use @media rules...

When playing around using browser devtools I see that if I just set `zoom:0.8` on the containing block, it looks perfect...

Thanks

Comment: Wait… is that still a relevant question for you or did you answer yourself with the `zoom` thing…?

Comment: First, you shouldn't be using pixel font sized. Point sizes would scale better.

Comment: Still relevent.  Zoom works fine but how dow I apply it conidtionally only on mobile devices ?

Comment: I voted to close, because the question is too broad. You need to look for 'responsive html emails' - there is loads of documentation out there.

Comment: The question is actually very specific and has no answer I could find on stack overflow (but I will try your search term too)